# Looping single post in a theme

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I am developing a wordpress theme. In `single.php` page I want to loop similar to this,

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <div class="post-heading-info">
               <!--Post heading info like title, category goes here -->
            </div>
<?php  endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php //sidebar widget goes here  ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <div class="post-content">
               <!--Post content and footer goes here-->
            </div>
<?php  endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

So, in the code above I am trying to loop all the basic information like title, category and time. The In the middle I want to put the sidebar and then in the second loop the content and the post's footer information.

I need this because of various options in single.php page layout. Basically I want keep all header info on top above all the widgets and post contents.

My question is, **Is this the code above acceptable as a good practice?**

Please help me in this and your few minutes from your life for my question would be really appreciated and helpful.

Comment: you are asking about 'good practice' - does that mean the code is actually working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly, you don't need to check with `is_single()` in `single.php`. WordPress will automatically recognize it for single post.
2. Secondly, breakdown your template with in parts. Such as break your main loop code in `content-single.php` and call it in `single.php` with `get_template_part('content', 'single')`.

So you `single.php` template will look like below-

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content', 'single-heading');?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php //sidebar widget goes here  ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('content', 'single');?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And create two files `content-single.php` and `content-single-heading.php` in the directory where `single.php` is. Then put below code in `content-single.php`-

```
<div class="post-content">
   <!--Post content and footer goes here-->
</div>
```

And this piece of code in `content-single-heading.php`-

```
<div class="post-heading-info">
   <!--Post heading info like title, category goes here -->
</div>
```

That will make your theme code more maintainable. And for further information read WordPress codex and analyze WordPress default themes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly normal, though you have some redundant bits.

`is_single()` check is unnecessary since in this case your template is already in that context.

`while( have_posts() )` is pretty much unnecessary too on single views (you only have *one* post, why *loop* through it?), though core themes tend to still include it.

Comment: Thanks you for your help and I will do the best thing for the theme.